# Add Logo In Front of QR Code

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code

I am making a QR Code generator using **zxing library** for Android. The app works just fine. However, I need to add a logo in the center of the generated **QR Code**. I have read [a tutorial from this web](https://skrymerdev.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/qr-code-generation-with-zxing/), but it is not close to what I'm looking for.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
private void generateQRCode_general(String data, ImageView img) throws WriterException {

    com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();

    String finaldata = Uri.encode(data, "utf-8");

    BitMatrix bm = writer.encode(finaldata, BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 150, 150);
    Bitmap ImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(180, 40, Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) {//width
        for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {//height
            ImageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    if (ImageBitmap != null) {
        qrcode.setImageBitmap(ImageBitmap);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.userInputError),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add some more details. Perhaps what it should look like. Add some screenshots.

Comment: I know your repu is not enough to upload image you can add image using http://tinypic.com/ and add link here

Comment: look at this project https://github.com/skrymer/qrbuilder

Comment: @mikepenz   the current application's appearance is like this tutorial: https://kreativdeveloper.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/android-generate-barcode/ .. and I want the QR Code to be like [this image] (http://www.ralree.com/newblog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/barcode-image.png)

Answer (score 0):

To add an image on top of another one you can use this method:

```
public Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap top, Bitmap bottom) 
{ 
    Bitmap combined = null; 

    int width, height = 0; 

    if(top.getWidth() > bottom.getWidth()) { 
      width = top.getWidth() + bottom.getWidth(); 
      height = top.getHeight(); 
    } else { 
      width = bottom.getWidth() + bottom.getWidth(); 
      height = top.getHeight(); 
    } 

    combined = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

    Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(combined); 

    comboImage.drawBitmap(top, 0f, 0f, null); 
    comboImage.drawBitmap(bottom, top.getWidth(), 0f, null); 

    return combined; 
}
```

This will merge together two bitmaps and there is a new resulting bitmap you can use. [Source](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas) (There are plenty other sources to do so)

If you want no new bitmap but just an image above another image you can use a `<RelativeLayout>` and place the two `<ImageView>`s inside it.

---

As an additional note i assume you will also have to check that the image does not overlap required dots of the QR-Code, which is a different topic then.